# Launch an application (choosing from installed on the device) using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, launch

I know how to launch an application using an intent and the application's package name.

Like this:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");

if (launchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

What I want to do is that the user could choose from the applications installed on his/her device, not a specific one.

How can I do so?

Also, I would like to open the other app inside a floating window (maybe in custom alert dialog or equivalent if there is a possibility to do so)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do so?

Use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to find all the activities that respond to the standard home screen launcher `Intent` structure (`ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`). Present those to the user (e.g., in a list). See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/Introspection/Launchalot).

> I would like to open the other app inside a floating window (maybe in custom alert dialog or equivalent if there is a possibility to do so)

You would need to implement your own mobile operating system. Even Android 7.0's multi-window support does not support this, except in cases where the device is already in freeform multi-window mode (e.g., Chrome OS). You are welcome to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to launch the activity into another task, which will give it a separate window on freeform multi-window devices.

Comment: Can I open the other application inside my application? Let's say I have a pop-up window or alert dialog so the launched application will show there?

Comment: @TsurYohananov: Not for how I would define as "inside my application".

Comment: Assuming I have a pop-up window or alert dialog so the launched application will show there?

Comment: @TsurYohananov: That is not possible in standard Android.